# Static libraries linking with g++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, g++, static-libraries

I have multiple static libraries created with Visual Studio and `Visual C++` compiler.

I am also using a CxxTest for unit testing. I created tests in .h files and generated test runner file `runner.cpp`.

Next thing I need to do is to compile that `runner.cpp` file.

`runner.cpp` uses one of the libraries, `CommonLib.lib`. `CommonLib.lib` doesn't have any aditional library dependencies.

`CommonLib.lib` headers are in my `CommonLib` project's directory.

I tried to compile `runner.cpp` using next command:

```
g++ -o runner.exe runner.cpp -L../x64/Release -l:CommonLib.lib -I../CommonLib 
-I../cxxtest-4.4
```

In `Release` directory there is a `CommonLib.lib` and headers are in a `CommonLib` directory. `cxxtest-4.4` directory contains CxxTest headers.

I am getting error:

```
undefined reference to `multiplyMatricesStandard(int**, int**, int, int, int**, int, int, int)
```

`multiplyMatricesStandard` is a function that has declaration in a header file located in a `CommonLib` directory. In same directory is also a cpp file that contains a definition for that function (I don't think cpp file's location really matters because I have created a static library).

I can't figure out why g++ can't see definition for a function.

Is there a problem if static library is not created with g++? If there is, how can i compile `runner.cpp` file without having to create static libraries with g++?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3253827/1410711) tells us that .lib files are specific to VS compilers only. You might need .a files for CommonLib.

Comment: More [info](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LibraryArchives-StaticAndDynamic.html) here. See if you can solve by trial and error.

Comment: Obvously your chances will improve dramatically if you use VS to build when relying on those dependencies. I would be surprised if you could succeed using g++ linking those .lib files.

Comment: I have the same problem when I compile with VS compiler using cl command.. I managed to to fix it by specifying all needed files to the g++. I have other problem now with CxxTest, I can't link because runner.cpp doesn't have main. By documentation it seems like main should be defined somewhere else automatically and I should be able to compile, but that is not the case. I posted another question for this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37644452/cxxtest-compiling-missing-main