# CxxTest compiling, missing main

Tags: c++, cxxtest

I am using CxxTest for unit testing. I followed the docs.

First command I executed was:

```
cxxtestgen --error-printer -o runner.cpp MyTestSuite1.h
```

Output of the command is `runner.cpp` file.

According to the documentation, next command should be:

```
g++ -o runner -I(location_of_the_cxxTest_headers) runner.cpp
```

but I am unable to execute it, I am receiving the error about missing entry point. In other words, `runner.cpp` is missing main.

Same thing happens with the test files included with CxxTest.

I am running Windows 8.1.

My question is marked as a duplicate, but I didn't find solution in the another question. I am not building a GUI application. Question is about CxxTest and how does it even start without a `main()` function? Where is the entry point?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [undefined reference to \`WinMain@16'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259714/undefined-reference-to-winmain16)

Comment: @Drop How is that a duplicate? I am not even building a GUI application.  According to the answer of that question my problem should be fixed with options:  -Wl,-subsystem,windows but it is not. Question is about CxxTest and how it is possible to run in console without main. My problem is that CxxTest doesn't generate main, how should then I start the tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution after looking at a python script `cxxtestgen.py` which is used to generate `runner.cpp`. There is an if statement at the beginning of a `writeMain(output)` function which writes `main` function in an output file:

```
if not (options.gui or options.runner):
       return
```

At least one of the two options, `--runner=CLASS` and `--gui=CLASS` is required when generating output file from test suites. After adding one option everything runs fine.

Comment: What argument do you add for CLASS?

Comment: @Sjoerd222888 I have used ParenPrinter. You can find possible values in the documentation for the CxxTest. http://cxxtest.com/guide.html#_test_listener_options